# Gradle copy without overwrite

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to avoid overwriting files, when using task `type:Copy`?

This is my task:

```
task unpack1(type:Copy)
{
    duplicatesStrategy= DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    delete(rootDir.getPath()+"/tmp")

    from zipTree(rootDir.getPath()+"/app-war/app.war")
    into rootDir.getPath()+"/tmp"


   duplicatesStrategy= DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
   from rootDir.getPath()+"/tmp"
   into  "WebContent"
}
```

I want to avoid to specify all the files using exclude 'file/file*'.

It looks like that `duplicatesStrategy= DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE` doesn't work. I read about an issue on gradle 0.9 but I'm using Gradle 2.1.

Is this problem still there?

Or am I misunderstanding how this task should be used properly?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Is there a way to avoid overwriting files"? In the code above, the second `into` will win over the first (there can be just one top-level `into`). Also, `into` and `from` can never be the same for the same Copy task.

Comment: Even if I run this task Gradle overwrite the file into WebContent

`task unpack(type:Copy)
{
 duplicatesStrategy= DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
 from rootDir.getPath()+"/tmp"
 into  "WebContent"
}`

Comment: I see what you mean. `DuplicatesStrategy` is about duplicates in copy sources (`from`). There is no configuration option to tell a `Copy` task not to overwrite files that already exist in the target directory, but you could probably achieve this using `eachFile`. See `Copy` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for details. You might also find a related sample in the `samples` directory of the `gradle-all` download.

Comment: Looking at the [docs for `duplicatesStrategy` in `Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy), the semantics seem to have changed (my emphasis): "The strategy to use when trying to copy more than one file _to the same destination_. "

Answer (score 9):

A further refinement of BugOrFeature's answer.  It's using simple strings for the from and into parameters, uses the CopySpec's destinationDir property to resolve the destination file's  relative path to a File:

```
task ensureLocalTestProperties(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree('/app-war/app.war')
    into 'WebContent'
    eachFile {
        if (it.relativePath.getFile(destinationDir).exists()) {
            it.exclude()
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always check first if the file exists in the destination directory:

```
task copyFileIfNotExists << {
  if (!file('destination/directory/myFile').exists())
    copy {
        from("source/directory")
        into("destination/directory")
        include("myFile")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sample based on Peter's comment:

```
task unpack1(type: Copy) {

    def destination = project.file("WebContent")
    from rootDir.getPath() + "/tmp"
    into destination
    eachFile {
        if (it.getRelativePath().getFile(destination).exists()) {
            it.exclude()
        }
    }
}
```